# How to assign to a new variable the current time using time::PrimitiveDateTime type?

Tags: rust

I'm using `time::PrimitiveDateTime` and I would like to create a new var with the current time but I cannot find how. Isn't there something like `now()`?

What about `Instant::now()`?

Example:

```rust
pub struct Player {
  updated_at: Option<PrimitiveDateTime>
}

impl Player {
    pub fn set_updated_at(&mut self) {
        let now = Instant::now();

        self.updated_at = Some(time::PrimitiveDateTime::from(now));
    }
```

But obviously this doesn't work:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `time::PrimitiveDateTime`, found struct `time::Instant` rustc E0308
```

Comment: What do you need the `PrimitiveDateTime` for? Why not use an `OffsetDateTime` instead?

Comment: Because I don't need timezone. I'm trying to understand what is the better type for my fields according to SeaORM types: https://www.sea-ql.org/SeaORM/docs/generate-entity/entity-structure. And since I don't need timezone I though that was the better. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is probably to use `PrimitiveDateTime::new` with `OffsetDateTime::now_(utc|local)`:

```
pub struct Player {
  updated_at: Option<PrimitiveDateTime>
}

impl Player {
    pub fn set_updated_at(&mut self) {
        let now = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();

        self.updated_at = Some(PrimitiveDateTime::new(now.date(), now.time()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the verbosity was done on purpose, so people have to consciously think about how they're losing the Offset data.

Comment: What do you suggest to use for date/time fields?

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest version, `OffsetDateTime` will have two `now`-style methods. One for UTC, one for the local time.

If for whatever reason you want a `PrimitiveDateTime` you can then of course  extract the date info from the `OffsetDateTime` and use those as arguments in the `PrimitiveDateTime::new()` method.